# hgk/hg view works with established repo but not with new repo

Tags: linux, mercurial, tortoisehg, hgrc

#### My vm system:

```
> uname -a
Linux xxx 2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Wed Mar 23 00:37:12 UTC 2016
i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

> python --version
Python 2.6.6

> hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.2.2)

> cat ~/.hgrc
[extensions]
hgext.hgk =
```

The native hg that came with centos6.7 is 1.4.4, but I updated it to 2.2.2 from rpm.

#### What I can do:

```
> cd ~/tmp/
> hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u
> cd jdk8u
> hg view
```

thg window displays as expected. No problems encountered.

#### Problem:

`hg view` encounters error when viewing newly created repo

```
> hg init ~/tmp/mizraim
> cd !$
> hg view
child process exited abnormally
    while executing
"exec $env(HG) --config ui.report_untrusted=false heads"
```

#### OTOH

[/media/sf_Temp] is shared drive between this Linux guest with Win7 host as [C:\Temp]

```
> cd /media/sf_Temp
> hg clone ~/tmp/mizraim
```

I am able to view [/media/sf_Temp/mizraim] as [C:\Temp\mizraim] using my win 7 version of TortoiseHg Workbench.

#### Question

- What is wrong with my `hg init` ?
- Why can't `hg view` view my newly created repo, but it can view the clone of jdk8u?
- What is hidden in the nooks of the [jdk8u/.hg] that I could hackplicate into [mizraim/.hg], to make `hg view` work on repo mizraim?

Answer (score 0):

In order:

> What is wrong with my `hg init`?

Nothing: it created a new, empty repository.

> Why can't `hg view` view my newly created repo, but it can view the clone of jdk8u?

There is nothing in it to view.

(In particular, `hg heads` prints no heads and exits with a failure status, which causes `hg view` to abort.  Probably `hg view` should just show you the empty repository, but that would not be particularly useful anyway.)

> What is hidden in the nooks of the [jdk8u/.hg] that I could hackplicate into [mizraim/.hg], to make `hg view` work on repo mizraim?

Nothing: you just need some revisions.

Comment: I had already tried checking/adding in and committing a text file. Did not help. So your answer is not relevant or applicable.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: your "how to reproduce the problem" example above does not include committing anything.  I verified that the problem occurs for me as well, but goes away as soon as I make a commit.